# Using only 1 EVP_PKEY while generating EC keys using OpenSSL 1.1

Tags: c++, c, openssl

In all of the examples I've seen of generating a key using elliptic curve via OpenSSL using the EVP high level functions, two `EVP_PKEY_CTX` and `EVP_PKEY` (total of 4) variables are needed:

1. One key/context pair for the parameter generation
2. One key/context pair for the actual key itself (initialized with the parameters).

Is it possible to consolidate this down to just one key/context pair for both? As I understand it, from the examples I've seen, the logic goes like this:

1. Create an `EVP_PKEY_CONTEXT` using whatever curve algorithm ID you want.
2. Initialize the context with `EVP_PKEY_paramgen_init()`.
3. Call whatever parameter-setting functions you want on the param context (e.g. `EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_ec_paramgen_curve_nid`).
4. Generate/finalize the parameters with `EVP_PKEY_paramgen` which gives you an `EVP_PKEY`.
5. Create an `EVP_PKEY_CTX` for the actual key, initialized with the param `EVP_PKEY` from the previous step.
6. Init the key with `EVP_PKEY_keygen_init()`.
7. Generate/finalize the key with `EVP_PKEY_keygen()`.

Is there any way to simplify this process? For example, can I just init a key, call the paramgen functions on the key, and then call `EVP_PKEY_keygen()`? This is sort of how it works with RSA key generation from my experience (you really only do the last 2 steps above, with step 3 happening in the middle).

The [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_PKEY_paramgen_init.html) states this, which seems to indicate the second context/key pair is unnecessary:

> After the call to EVP_PKEY_keygen_init() or EVP_PKEY_paramgen_init() algorithm specific control operations can be performed to set any appropriate parameters for the operation.
>
> The functions EVP_PKEY_keygen() and EVP_PKEY_paramgen() can be called more than once on the same context if several operations are performed using the same parameters.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but it seems like it's saying you can invoke the parameter-setting functions after calling `EVP_PKEY_keygen_init()`, instead of using the `paramgen` functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The separate parameter generation stage is really intended for algorithms such as Diffie-Hellman where this is necessary. For EC you almost always use "standard" sets of parameters (i.e. well known curves). Therefore OpenSSL allows you to shortcut this and only do the key generation if you already know what parameters you want to use. In the case of the `EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_ec_paramgen_curve_nid()` macro it is explicitly documented to be usable by either the parameter generation or key generation options:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_ec_paramgen_curve_nid.html

> The EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_ec_paramgen_curve_nid() sets the EC curve for EC parameter
>   generation to B. For EC parameter generation this macro must be called
>   or an error occurs because there is no default curve.
>   This function can also be called to set the curve explicitly when
>   generating an EC key.

So the code to generate a key using the P-256 curve (NID_X9_62_prime256v1) might look like this:

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>

int main(void) {
    EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx;
    EVP_PKEY *pkey = NULL;
    int ret = 1;

    ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_EC, NULL);
    if (ctx == NULL)
        goto err;
    if (EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(ctx) <= 0)
        goto err;
    if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_ec_paramgen_curve_nid(ctx, NID_X9_62_prime256v1) <= 0)
        goto err;

    /* Generate key */
    if (EVP_PKEY_keygen(ctx, &pkey) <= 0)
        goto err;

    printf("Success!\n");

    ret = 0;
 err:
    EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx);
    return ret;
}
```

This only needs a single `EVP_PKEY` and a single `EVP_PKEY_CTX`.