# Generate ECDSA keypair in C++

Tags: c++, openssl, cryptography, ecdsa

I have been trying to find a way of generating an ECDSA private & public key in C++ but found nothing.

The program should generate an ECDSA private key and then get the corresponding public key. I'm sure OpenSSL supports this but can't find anything in their documentation.

EDIT: This is for a blockchain based currency implementation which is being written in c++. I originally prototyped it in javascript and so I had access to simple to use libraries like javascript.security to access EC pair storage and generation. i have not been able to fimd any form of (releavnt) documentation for cpp liabys like openssl or cryptopp so i havent tried any code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add your code and what you tried so far and possible error messages you encounteded as SO isn't a coding service but a q&a forum. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm going to bet that there isn't a single ECC library that doesn't support EC key pair creation. Besides it being basic functionality, it's darn easy to implement as well. This comes down to a library recommendation and code sample; both are considered off topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't given any details, it sample just creates a 256v1 curve EC private key.

The easiest way is to use the [EVP](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man7/evp.html) API in openssl, mainly the [EVP_PKEY_keygen](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/EVP_PKEY_keygen.html) API. The rest of the code is setting up what type of key (EC in this case) and then saving the key out to a file.

```
template<typename T, typename D>
std::unique_ptr<T, D> make_handle(T* handle, D deleter)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T, D>{handle, deleter};
}

void print_openssl_error(std::string const& function)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    ERR_error_string_n(ERR_get_error(), buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    std::cerr << "openssl function " << function << " failed with " << buffer << "\n";
}

bool create_ec_private_key()
{
    // Create the context for the key generation
    auto kctx = make_handle(EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_EC, nullptr), EVP_PKEY_CTX_free);
    if(!kctx)
    {
        print_openssl_error("EVP_PKEY_CTX_new"s);
        return false;
    }

    // Generate the key
    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(kctx.get()))
    {
        print_openssl_error("EVP_PKEY_keygen_init"s);
        return false;
    }

    //  We're going to use the ANSI X9.62 Prime 256v1 curve
    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_ec_paramgen_curve_nid(kctx.get(), NID_X9_62_prime256v1)) 
    {
        print_openssl_error("EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_ec_paramgen_curve_nid"s);
        return false;
    }

    EVP_PKEY *pkey_temp = nullptr;
    if (1 != EVP_PKEY_keygen(kctx.get(), &pkey_temp))
    {
        print_openssl_error("EVP_PKEY_keygen"s);
        return false;
    }

    // write out to pem file
    auto pkey = make_handle(pkey_temp, EVP_PKEY_free);

    auto file = make_handle(BIO_new_file("ecprivatekey.pem", "w"), BIO_free);
    if(!file)
    {
        print_openssl_error("BIO_new_file"s);
        return false;
    }

    if(!PEM_write_bio_PrivateKey(file.get(), pkey.get(), nullptr, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr))
    {
        print_openssl_error("PEM_write_bio_PrivateKey"s);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: A good answer. The key generation can be simplified though. You do not need the separate paramgen step. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56954187/using-only-1-evp-pkey-while-generating-ec-keys-using-openssl-1-1/57008493#57008493

Comment: Thanks @MattCaswell, I didn't know that.  I will update my answer with your information.